# Why the static message is not coming from ajax file if no data found in mysql database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a very strange problem and couldn't figure it out. I am working with AJAX/PHP and fetching the data from mysql database on user interaction by ajax call. Everything is working very fine and no problem at all. But only one issue which is persisting is when the data is not found in mysql database, then a user-friendly message is not returned from the server ajax file - the one part works and other doesn't. Here is my code -

This is my first file where the form reside (full code is not there; only js code) -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selcustomer").change(function(){
        var customers_id = $(this).val();
        if(customers_id > 0)
        {
            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: startRequest,
                url: "ajax/ajax.php",
                cache: false,
                data: "customers_id="+customers_id,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                    if(data != "No result found.")
                    {
                        $("#img_preloader").hide();
                        $("#error").html('');
                        // $("#txtfname").val(data.fname);
                        // $("#txtlname").val(data.lname);
                        for(var key in data)
                        {
                            document.getElementById("txt"+key).value = data[key];
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#img_preloader").hide();
                        $("#error").html(data);
                        $("input").each(function(){
                           $(this).val(''); 
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $("#error").html('');
            $("input").each(function(){
                $(this).val(''); 
            });
        }
    });
});

function startRequest()
{
    $("#img_preloader").show();
}
</script>
```

And this is my server-side ajax file (php file) which interacts with database -

```
<?php
include("../includes/db-config.php");
if(isset($_POST["customers_id"]))
{
    $customers_id = $_POST["customers_id"];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tb_customers` WHERE `customers_id` = '$customers_id'";
    $rs = mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
        $customers_first_name = $row['customers_first_name'];
        $customers_last_name = $row['customers_last_name'];
        $customers_email_id = $row['customers_email_id'];
        $customers_phone_no = $row['customers_phone_no'];
        $customers_address_line_1 = $row['customers_address_line_1'];
        $customers_address_line_2 = $row['customers_address_line_2'];
        $customers_country = $row['customers_country'];

        $data = array('fname' => $customers_first_name, 'lname' => $customers_last_name, 'emailid' => $customers_email_id, 'phoneno' => $customers_phone_no, 'addressline1' => $customers_address_line_1, 'addressline2' => $customers_address_line_2, 'country' => $customers_country);

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No result found.";
    }
}
?>
```

The if part is working fine but when no data is found in database the else part is not sending the data back to jQuery code. I checked in browser console and saw the else part is returning the response but the jquery code in success: part of $.ajax is not running - neither within if, nor in else and also not outside of if/else. I mean to say that a simple alert is not fired with data under success when no data is found in mysql database. But when i remove all the data in ajax/php file and say simply write 123 then alert comes with 123 but not when the actual code is there. Can you plz tell me what is the issue behind this strange problem?

Comment: But why i will have to use if(!mysql_query($query)) because the query is executed successfully and tells no data is found - means no record in the database. It is the only else part of php file not showing in the success of jquery/ajax code.

Comment: sorry I just misunderstood... you should try Kamehameha's ans.. as you have passed `dataType: "json"` in your jquery function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datatype is set to JSON in your AJAX call, so the return value must be a valid JSON. 
When you are encountering the else condition, you are returning something that is not JSON.
Try this -

```
else
{
    echo json_encode("No result found.");
}
```

Or something more flexible-

```
else{
    echo json_encode(Array("err"=>"No result found."));
}
```

**EDIT-**

> ...But when i remove all the data in ajax/php file and say simply write
>   123 then alert comes with 123...

That is because a `123` (number) is [valid JSON](http://json.org/). Instead of `123`, try writing `No result` and an error would be thrown, because `No result` (a string) needs quotes(which is taken care when you use `json_encode`).

Comment: Wow! that's great! It works and problem solved. Thanks. But one thing is still teasing me - you said the return value must be a valid json - right; i understand, but as i told in my question when i remove all the code in server side ajax php file and simply wrote 123 then why this number still came in jquery code as i did not write it in json format and also did not change the dataType in my $.ajax code. So how did it work?

Comment: Your second solution is also good. But i will have to modify my jquery ajax code to success: function(data){ if(data.error != "No result found.")..... and in else part for printing the error message - $("#error").html(data.error);

Comment: @Sachin frankly, I had not read the second part of your question(the one with 123 bit), and I was quite surprised with the result, when I tried it on my own. Gimme a couple of mins to try and sort out why 123 is valid.. :)

Comment: @Sachin The second solution is included because it's always a good idea to always have a key-value pair of err, because when you are parsing the response in JavaScript, you can first check if one of the keys is "err" and then determine what to do(show it to user, take care of it on your own, etc.)

Comment: Another think i would like to ask you which is the best way to putting the returned json data into html elements like text field or div? I can have two ways - one is $("#txtfname").val(data.fname); and other is the for in loop - for(var key in data)
      {
       document.getElementById("txt"+key).value = data[key];
      } But in loop, i did a tweak, the returned json object key is the part of the id of an element, for example - i have txtfname is the id of a textfield and returned key is fname then i combined both to access the id with the key. So is it good or any correct way?

Comment: @Sachin I guess the looping trick is neat, but you have to take care of not changing the id names :). It all depends on how easy it is for you and if it will break if code in the future will change(and mostly it will).

Comment: I read your edit. Yes it will be the reason. Well regarding my question about the putting the json returned data in html element, i just wondered how the people do it in industry?